# SQL Server where Clause on JSON Field

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, where-clause, sql-server-json

I have a table

```
ID |  Start Date       | End Date          | Summary
---+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------
1  | 2020-01-01T09:20  | 2020-01-01T09:30  | {"total":20,"totalError":10}
1  | 2020-01-02T09:20  | 2020-01-02T10:55  | {"total":10,"totalError":5}
```

I want to query `where totalError > 0`

```
Select * 
from runLog 
where Summary.totalError > 0
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
select * from runLog where json_value(summary, '$.totalError') > 0
```